# Inappropriate "Ads by WGX" ad on Academia and History

Tags: support, inappropriate-advertisements

Reporting a highly inappropiate ad seen on Academia (and History). No link URL visible without clicking. This ad (or another on the page) also tried to open popups and new browser tabs. Please clean up the ads you serve.

> [image]

Comment: You saw a hovering or pop up ad? I'm not sure SE ads can cause that. Perhaps your browser has malware?

Comment: The hillarity of googleing for it is... it gives me a bunch of dodgy malware removal tools - Does look potentially like malware though

Comment: While SE did change their ad policy drastically and now allows evil ads, this one isn't on SE side, it's some external software hijacking your browser, as others pointed out already.

Answer (score 20):

The example ad you've posted says "Ads by WGX". Those seem to caused by a well known kind of malware. A quick Google search for "WGX spam ads" found several sites providing instructions on how to remove it (I can't vouch for their accuracy).

You probably ought to update the malware scanner on your computer and scan your computer for malware; if that malware got in, there could be others.

Comment: I have only seen this ad on Stack Exchange pages and no signs that something on my machine is causing this.

Comment: @Raidri the malware is smart enough to hijack only specific pages. It is still 100% a malware, not something on SE side.

Comment: @Raidri SE ads _have_ been getting worse recently, but not _that_ bad. SE still only serves ads in the designated ad spots; that's not one of them. There's a banner ad, and there are ad slots in the sidebar, but definitely no floating ads. Either SE has been hijacked, or you have - one of those is far more likely than the other.

Comment: No suspicious programs or browser extensions. Multiple virus scans from inside and ouside Windows without finding anything. I still have no idea where the ad came from. But I have now installed an adblocker, so hopefully, it will not come up again.